# Django blank page

Tags: python, django

This is my `index.html` file:

```
{% extends "base_site.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% if info %}
    <ul>
    {% for object in info %}
        {{ Hello }}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No objects are available.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from notendur.models import *
from django.views import generic

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'notendur/index.html'
    context_object_name = "info"

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published polls."""
        return Information.objects.all()
```

This is my     `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Information(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class InformationChild(models.Model):
    information = models.ForeignKey(Information)
    child_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.child_text
```

When I start the server, however, nothing appears. This has to be some url-link issue, because the else clause doesn't even activate. Perhaps you want `urls.py` as well?

Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Replacing info with nonsense appears to activate the else clause. This must, then, have something to do with info not being found. It is incorrect, in fact. What should be there instead of info? I want to get the Information objects.

Comment: Change `.all()` in your `get_queryset` to `.none()` and see if the `{% else %}` fires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not in the use of `info`, it's in what's inside the for loop: `{{ Hello }}` is not an item in the context. Use `{{ object.title }}`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that doesn't break my code like many of the things I tried before. But it still yields the else clause. I don't think I've defined info anywhere. Does Django realize I'm talking about the objects in Information.objects.all()?

Comment: Now I'm confused. You said you had a blank page, and only got the else clause when you replaced 'info' with nonsense. But you're now saying you get the else clause anyway - which is it?

Comment: I commented on my post saying it now yields the else clause.

Comment: Yes, when you replace it with nonsense. So put it back to info.

Comment: It works! I had accidentally named info "igjifjov". Fixing that solved the problem. Haha.

thanks a lot. Can you tell me how it recognizes info, though? I'm not good with django.

Comment: You named it "info" by declaring `context_object_name = "info"` in your view class.